# how can I send as json with client-oauth2?

Tags: typescript, auth0

so I have this code

```
    const auth0 = new ClientOAuth2({
        clientId: 'my id',
        clientSecret: 'my secret',
        accessTokenUri: 'https://myorg.auth0.com/oauth/token',
        scopes: ['version:read']
    });

    auth0.credentials.getToken().then(tok => {
        console.log(tok);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

but I'm getting a 403 back

this is what auth0 suggests I send

```
 calebcushing$ curl --request POST   --url https://myorg.auth0.com/oauth/token   --header 'content-type: application/json'   --data '{"client_id":"my id","client_secret":"my secret","audience":"http://localhost:4000","grant_type":"client_credentials"}'
```

```
curl 'https://myorg.auth0.com/oauth/token' -H 'authority: myorg.auth0.com' -H 'accept: application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'origin: http://localhost:3000' -H 'authorization: Basic encoded' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  --data 'scope=version%3Aread&grant_type=client_credentials'
```

I'm not married to `client-oauth2` so if another library is the better option that would be fine. I would prefer using an oauth library though so I don't have to do all the coordination dance. bonus points if it will just automatically do the refetch of tokens and such, when making requests to the resource server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,  I think you are trying to execute client credentials grant type and obtain Auth0 Management API token. You can use auth0 node sdk ([auth0](https://auth0.github.io/node-auth0/module-auth.AuthenticationClient.html#clientCredentialsGrant)).

Install the package:

`npm install auth0`

```
var AuthenticationClient = require('auth0').AuthenticationClient;

var auth0 = new AuthenticationClient({
  domain: '{YOUR_ACCOUNT}.auth0.com',
  clientId: '{CLIENT_ID}',
  clientSecret: '{CLIENT_SECRET}'
});

auth0.clientCredentialsGrant(
  {
    audience: 'https://{YOUR_ACCOUNT}.auth0.com/api/v2/',
    scope: '{MANAGEMENT_API_SCOPES}'
  },
  function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error.
    }
    console.log(response.access_token);
  }
);
```

You can also use any HTTP client. For example, fetch or request.

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/client-credentials